# Redirecting root domain to www on Heroku Hostname based SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

I'm trying to redirect my root domain: http://[sitename].com to https://www.[sitename].com

- Backend is rails on heroku with a Hostname Base SSL.
- My domain is registered on GoDaddy.

And, here is what I've tried:

- In my ApplicationController, I have a before_filter called redirect_to_https. And the contents of that are:

  ```
  def redirect_to_https
      puts "In Redirect"
      redirect_to "https://www.[sitename].com#{request.fullpath}" unless request.ssl? || !Rails.env.production?
  end
  ```

When I browse to the root domain of the website, I do not see the "In redirect" in the logs. So, clearly that redirect is not actually working.

Any ideas?

Comment: puts doesn't write to your log file. `Use Rails.logger.info`

Comment: thanks! but it actually does (as seen from my log files from many other locations in the code base)

Answer (score 0):

I would look at [Rack-rewrite](http://rubygems.org/gems/rack-rewrite), it's a much more efficient lower level library that does all this sort of thing really well.  Alternatively, roll your own:

http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/05/configuring-rails-3-https-ssl/

Comment: thanks but not sure how that helps. the second link that you have provided just states that I should force_ssl. how will that help with redirection from somesite.com TO www.somesite.com.

Comment: That's why I mentioned Rack rewrite

Comment: cool - i thought it was just an alternative to the other link you mentioned.